# How to handle authentication exceptions on API REST with JWT authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I implemented an **API REST** that uses **Spring Security** and **JWT**.

All is working fine except when trying to handle exceptions thrown by the authentication provider.

Here is my security configuration function:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable().formLogin().disable()
    .httpBasic().disable().logout().disable() 
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
    .and().authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated()
    .and().authenticationProvider(tokenAuthenticationProvider)
        .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

As you can see I'm using a custom provider and filter in order to use the JWT service that I implemented (using `io.jsonwebtoken` so don't worry about security vulnerabilities).

I'm handling most of the exceptions with a `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. But this handler doesn't catch exceptions thrown on the Provider.

So, I tried to implement an `AuthenticationnEntryPoint` to handle those exceptions. But that didn't worked.

I turns out my custom `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` is caching the authentication exceptions raised on the **Provider**. I tried to re-throw the exception but the entry point wasn't caching it.

Right now I'm resolving those exceptions on the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` on the `unsuccessfulAuthentication` function:

```
@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
    int status = ...
    String jsonString = ...
    response.setStatus(status);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(jsonString); 
}
```

I don't really like this solution and would prefer to handle those exceptions separately from the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

Comment: i have read your code about 5 times and i cant really understand what it is you want to do. Spring has an implemented `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that will catch all thrown `AccessDeniedExceptions` and `AuthenticationException` in the filterchain. `BadCredentialException` is a subtype of a `AuthenticationException` so it gets caught and converted there to a proper status code.

What i dont understand is why you are writing a lot of custom filters when there are already a tonne of customizable filters in spring that you can use and customize to your needs.

Comment: Also a `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is a `context` interface for implementing a login initializer. Its not a class where you catch exceptions. If you look in the api you can see what types are already implemented, for instance `BasicAuthenticationPoint` (basic authentication), `BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint` (oauth2 and tokens) etc.

Comment: i suggest you instead read up on how jwt in spring security works and implement it using their recommended way. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thanks for your comments. The authentication logic is working fine so no need to re-implement it (didn't knew that spring suports JWT that way). The custom filter is needed in order to use my custom implementation of JWT (I'm using a library). Right now I just deleted the entry point and I'm just handling the exceptions on the filter (which I belive is not very pretty).

Comment: I'm editing the question with the changes I made in past over to clarify.

Comment: it is not recommended to do custom security solutions, it is bad practice. Spring security is production tested, and battle tested in thousands of applications world wide. I highly recommend you use the tools provided by spring security than writing your own security solution.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I'm not really implementing anything related to security. I'm just customizing things that spring already have. I'm using io.jsonwebtoken to create and validate the tokens so I don't see the problem here. I let spring to handle all security I'm just telling him to use my tokenService implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232241/discussion-between-arracso-and-toerktumlare).

Comment: There are several aspects here. Spring already comes with a jwt library included `jose` so pulling in another exposes you application to more ”unknown code” which increases the lines of ”unknown code” in your project. Hemce increasing the attack vector.

Comment: Parsing and validating the jwt manually is ”security”. There has been several security issues over the years with developers and applications not verifying signatures correctly before parsing, or parsing claims faulty etc. So one should strive  to use the battle tested framework as much as possible and not inventing the wheel when there is already one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions are handled by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`.

- If the exception is of type `org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException` (any subclass), it will flow into the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, which it sounds like isn't the case for you.
- If the exception is of type `org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException` (or a subclass), it will flow into the `AccessDeniedHandler`.
- Any other exception will be re-thrown.

If you desire to handle something in the "Any other" category, you can either implement your own filter higher up the filter chain, or do as you have done to handle it. See the section on [ExceptionTranslationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-exceptiontranslationfilter) for more info. Here's how [that class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java#L121) is implemented.

**Note:** As pointed out by other commenters, it would generally be recommended to stick "close to home" if there's an out-of-the-box solution for your JWT needs. But implementing filters to add to the Spring Security filter chain is a perfectly good way to extend Spring Security's capabilities for your own application. There are many use cases where you will find this a useful (and necessary) approach.